# OLAP Cube have bad perfomance

Tags: asp.net, olap, cube

I have asp.net site. In this site there are some mdx queries (use Adomd library). After publishing site in localhost at local machine perfomance is good, the longest query to cube take 170 ms. But when I published this site to another virtual catalog on diferent machine (the same IIS configuration, site use the same connection string, only one difference - it's a version of MS SQL Server. On my local computer it is Developer edition and in different machine it's Standard edition) the perfomance is bad, the shortest query to cube take about one second. Can I increase perfomance in the second machine? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can the two sites use the same OLAP connection string if the two databases are on different machines? I guess you are using "." or "localhost"? I suggest you show us both connection strings (with passwords excluded!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance of OLAP cube for 2 different machines depends on various things such as network speed, connection string, OLAP configuration in the host server, partition location etc. You need to check these to know where the bottleneck is.